# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker in UWP

Tags: google-api, win-universal-app

I'm faced with problem in GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker. At 2560x1440 resolution 10.6 authorization form is reduced in size and it is difficult to see. Who is this face? Is it possible to like something to fix it?

[image]

Best regards, Dmitry